# IGMP v3 JOIN sent but no traffic from switch

Tags: multicast, cisco

I'm trying to join an IGMP multicast stream from a Centos 8 machine but after sending a JOIN, there is no traffic coming from the switch.

Simple connection:

```
MUX <-----------> cisco3850 <--------> Centos8
192.168.117.13                         192.168.117.21
```

The upstream switch (cisco catalyst 3850) is fed an MPEG-TS to 239.1.1.1:4000 from the MUX.

I've tried both `socat` and my own program to open a socket, join the stream, and hold the socket open.  Both send the same IGMP join message as confirmed by wireshark:

```
Internet Group Management Protocol
    [IGMP Version: 3]
    Type: Membership Report (0x22)
    Reserved: 00
    Checksum: 0xe9fb [correct]
    [Checksum Status: Good]
    Reserved: 0000
    Num Group Records: 1
    Group Record : 239.1.1.1  Change To Exclude Mode
        Record Type: Change To Exclude Mode (4)
        Aux Data Len: 0
        Num Src: 0
        Multicast Address: 239.1.1.1
```

Using `ip route add` I created routes for multicast groups to the interface:

```
224.0.0.0/4 dev eth1 scope link
225.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 scope link
239.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 scope link
```

and `cat /proc/net/igmp` shows the group has been joined:

```
cat /proc/net/igmp
Idx     Device    : Count Querier       Group    Users Timer    Reporter
3       eth1      :     2      V3
                                030101E1     1 0:00000000               0
                                010000E0     1 0:00000000               0
```

I *suspect* this is a problem with the switch rather than a Linux problem, but the customer (who owns the switch) says everything is fine.

What else can I do on the Linux side to investigate/fix this issue?

If it is an issue on the switch then what?  What needs to be configured there? (need to explain to customer)

---

For reference, my program which joins and holds the socket open looks like:

```
// Error checking omitted for brevity
fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes);

memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
saddr.sin_family      = PF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = mcastAddr;
saddr.sin_port        = htons(port);

bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr);

struct ip_mreq mcastReq;
mcastReq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = mcastAddr;
&mcastReq.imr_interface.s_addr = interfaceAddr;

setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mcastReq, sizeof(mcastReq);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the customer switch could not/would not activate IGMPv3, so we set our machine to use IGMP v2 by creating a file under `/etc/sysctl.d`.

The JOIN then worked, but Linux did not respond to multicast membership queries so the switch dropped the stream after 1-2 minutes (even though we had `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter` set to zero.

It turns out to fully disable return path validation, we needed to set all of the `rp_filter` settings to zero (including explicitly listing the interface)

```
# Set IGMP Version for eth1
# Set to '2' or '3' depending on what is enabled in the switch
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.force_igmp_version = 2

# Disable source route verification
# In addition to 90-torque.conf, also explicitly set eth1 to ignore
# return path validation
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
```