# Centos8 does not respond to IGMP v2 membership queries

Tags: centos, rhel, multicast

In troubleshooting a general issue why a [Centos 8 box doesn't receive multicast data after sending a JOIN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674956/igmp-v3-join-sent-but-no-traffic-from-switch), analyzing with wireshark also shows the Centos box not responding to IGMP v2 membership queries.

In this case, multicast address 225.1.1.3 has been joined, and can be confirmed with `netstat -g`:

```
# netstat -g
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      224.0.0.1
eth0            1      224.0.0.1
eth1            1      225.1.1.3
```

Which matches the info in `/proc/net/igmp`

```
# cat /proc/net/igmp
Idx     Device    : Count Querier       Group    Users Timer    Reporter
3       eth1      :     3      V3
                                030101E1     1 0:00000000               0
                                010101EF     1 0:00000000               0
                                010000E0     1 0:00000000               0
```

But very clearly, it is not sending responses to the v2 Membership Query message:

```
 1881 2544.437502942 192.168.105.253 → 225.1.1.3    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, specific for group 225.1.1.3
 1883 2545.439116776 192.168.105.253 → 225.1.1.3    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, specific for group 225.1.1.3
 1890 2555.526695862 192.168.105.253 → 224.0.0.1    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, general
 1936 2615.525812650 192.168.105.253 → 224.0.0.1    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, general
 1977 2675.524651646 192.168.105.253 → 224.0.0.1    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, general
 1981 2680.487871978 192.168.105.253 → 225.1.1.3    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, specific for group 225.1.1.3
 1983 2681.488403894 192.168.105.253 → 225.1.1.3    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, specific for group 225.1.1.3
 1999 2702.808993240 192.168.117.21 → 224.0.0.22   IGMPv3 54 Membership Report / Leave group 225.1.1.3
 2000 2702.826998740 192.168.117.21 → 224.0.0.22   IGMPv3 54 Membership Report / Leave group 225.1.1.3
 2002 2704.929915370 192.168.117.21 → 224.0.0.22   IGMPv3 54 Membership Report / Join group 225.1.1.3 for any sources
 2003 2705.331977636 192.168.117.21 → 224.0.0.22   IGMPv3 54 Membership Report / Join group 225.1.1.3 for any sources
 2023 2735.523170767 192.168.105.253 → 224.0.0.1    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, general
 2063 2795.522407972 192.168.105.253 → 224.0.0.1    IGMPv2 60 Membership Query, general
```

A number of posts mentioned disabling the firewall and/or setting a route. But the firewall is off and the route has been added. Problem still there.

How can configure Centos8 to respond to the membership queries?

```
# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit firewalld.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)

# ip route
10.1.0.0/16 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.21
30.0.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 30.0.0.21
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1003
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2 scope link metric 1004
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth3 scope link metric 1005 linkdown
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.21 linkdown
192.168.117.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.117.21
224.0.0.0/4 dev eth1 scope link
234.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 scope link
235.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 scope link
239.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 scope link
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `multicast` flag on the multicast routes?  I don't know if it will fix your issue but the flag must be there for a reason.  Perhaps it acts as a flag so that you don't need to disable `rp_filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though we had `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter` set to zero, it turns out to fully disable return path validation, we needed to set all of the `rp_filter` settings to zero (including explicitly listing the interface).

We put a file under `/etc/sysctl.d` like this:

```
# Set IGMP Version for eth1
# Set to '2' or '3' depending on what is enabled in the switch
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.force_igmp_version = 2

# Disable source route verification
# In addition to 90-torque.conf, also explicitly set eth1 to ignore
# return path validation
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
```